# Как получить get атрибут в LineReceiver в Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

Делаю чат по https://ferretfarmer.net/2013/09/05/tutorial-real-time-chat-with-django-twisted-and-websockets-part-2/ этому мануалу. В LineReceiver необходимо получить id сессии из GET атрибута ws://localhost:8000?/ws/session_id=abc123. Как это реализовать? Сейчас код такой, каким я его представлял:

```
class MyChat(basic.LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "New client: {0}".format(self)
        print self.kwargs['session_id']
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
```

Comment: Прошу пощения, обновил ссылку - другая часть

Comment: руководство похоже использует [заброшенный патч (4+ лет)](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/websocket-4173-4/twisted/web/websockets.py), который не был добавлен в twisted. Информация по параметрам запроса в `MyChat` недоступна. Посмотрите в исходном коде где `request` доступен (на уровне: `WebSocketsResource.render` и `lookupProtocolForFactory.lookupProtocol`). [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/python/) выглядит более актуальной реализацией WebSocket для Twisted.

Comment: Не подскажете, как его подключить к django?

Comment: это независимые вещи. Django это WSGI приложение (синхронная модель), а autobahn работает поверх асинхронных библиотек таких как twisted, asyncio. Как их связать, зависит от проекта, например, django может события с помощью http POST публиковать по адресу, предоставленному асинхронной стороной (twisted), которая уже, используя web socket, может доставить событие клиентам.  Я не знаю, какие библиотеки принято в django использовать, чтобы с web socket подружить.